# How to customize simple HTML Range Slider in React

Tags: css, reactjs, slider

I am first time using the range slider in react.
I am using basic html slider in react like this:

```
<input name="cost" id="range"
       type="range" 
       value={this.props.cost}
       min="0" max="100000"
       step="1" onChange={this.props.updateRange}
 />
```

and applied some css to it and now it looks like this:
[image]

But I want to customize it like this: [image]

I need help in 2 things:

1. how to customize css like this
2. current value to be displayed beneath the slider and moving along with it(in React)

Please help !!!

Comment: You can't do what you want simply with an input element, you would need to build something more custom or use a library

Comment: Post your working code here, then it will be easier to help